# Delete cases within each group based on the place of the case in the group and time interval

Tags: r, dplyr

This is the example data I have：

```
data<- data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,4),rep(5,3),rep(6,3),rep(7,4),rep(8,5)),
                  test_results=c("POS","NEG","NA","NA", 
                                 "NA","NEG","POS","NA","NA",
                                 "NEG","NEG","NEG","POS","NA",
                                 "NA","NA","NA","NA",
                                 "NEG","NEG","NEG",
                                 "POS","POS","POS",
                                 "NEG","NEG","NEG","NA",
                                 "POS","POS","POS","NA","POS"),
                  Test_date=c("2000-1-1","2002-1-2","2003-1-1","2004-1-1",
                              "2000-2-1","2000-10-1","2002-10-2","2002-11-1","2002-12-1",
                              "2000-1-1","2002-1-1","2004-1-1","2006-1-1","2008-1-1",
                              "2000-1-1","2001-1-1","2002-1-1","2003-1-1",
                              "2000-1-1","2002-1-1","2004-1-1",
                              "2002-1-1","2004-1-1","2006-1-1",
                              "2000-1-1","2002-2-1","2003-12-1","2003-12-30",
                              "2002-3-1","2004-5-2","2005-12-30","2005-12-31","2007-9-10"))
```

I want to remove the 'NA' after the 'POS' in each ID, if the time interval between the "NA" and the "POS" is less than 3 months.
This is the intended result:

```
data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3),rep(3,5),rep(4,4),rep(5,3),rep(6,3),rep(7,4),rep(8,4)),
                  test_results=c("POS","NEG","NA","NA", 
                                 "NA","NEG","POS",
                                 "NEG","NEG","NEG","POS","NA",
                                 "NA","NA","NA","NA",
                                 "NEG","NEG","NEG",
                                 "POS","POS","POS",
                                 "NEG","NEG","NEG","NA",
                                 "POS","POS","POS","POS"),
                  Test_date=c("2000-1-1","2002-1-2","2003-1-1","2004-1-1",
                              "2000-2-1","2000-10-1","2002-10-2",
                              "2000-1-1","2002-1-1","2004-1-1","2006-1-1","2008-1-1",
                              "2000-1-1","2001-1-1","2002-1-1","2003-1-1",
                              "2000-1-1","2002-1-1","2004-1-1",
                              "2002-1-1","2004-1-1","2006-1-1",
                              "2000-1-1","2002-2-1","2003-12-1","2003-12-30",
                              "2002-3-1","2004-5-2","2005-12-30","2007-9-10"))
```

I had many attempts to find a good way to achieve this but did not get the solution. Any insights will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(data)[
  ,
  Test_date := ymd(Test_date)
][
  ,
  Q := c(NA, Test_date[test_results == "POS"] %m+% months(3))[cumsum(test_results == "POS") + 1],
  ID
][!replace(rep(FALSE, .N), test_results == "NA" & Test_date <= Q, TRUE)][
  ,
  Q := NULL
][]
```

which gives

```
   ID test_results  Test_date
 1:  1          POS 2000-01-01
 2:  1          NEG 2002-01-02
 3:  1           NA 2003-01-01
 4:  1           NA 2004-01-01
 5:  2           NA 2000-02-01
 6:  2          NEG 2000-10-01
 7:  2          POS 2002-10-02
 8:  3          NEG 2000-01-01
 9:  3          NEG 2002-01-01
10:  3          NEG 2004-01-01
11:  3          POS 2006-01-01
12:  3           NA 2008-01-01
13:  4           NA 2000-01-01
14:  4           NA 2001-01-01
15:  4           NA 2002-01-01
16:  4           NA 2003-01-01
17:  5          NEG 2000-01-01
18:  5          NEG 2002-01-01
19:  5          NEG 2004-01-01
20:  6          POS 2002-01-01
21:  6          POS 2004-01-01
22:  6          POS 2006-01-01
23:  7          NEG 2000-01-01
24:  7          NEG 2002-02-01
25:  7          NEG 2003-12-01
26:  7           NA 2003-12-30
27:  8          POS 2002-03-01
28:  8          POS 2004-05-02
29:  8          POS 2005-12-30
30:  8          POS 2007-09-10
    ID test_results  Test_date
```

---

A `dplyr` option following a similar idea

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
data %>%
  mutate(Test_date = ymd(Test_date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Q = c(NA, Test_date[test_results == "POS"] %m+% months(3))[cumsum(test_results == "POS") + 1]) %>%
  filter(!replace(rep(FALSE, n()), test_results == "NA" & Test_date <= Q, TRUE)) %>%
  select(-Q) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you! I have no experience in data. table. A little overwhelmed by the [], can you elaborate a little about the logic of these [] and the formula?

Comment: @Jie `[]` is shorthand for `print()`

Comment: It really works on the example data, thank you! But I couldn't fully understand the code after reading through the help files in R carefully. Especially the code in the second and third [], also what's the meaning of the last empty []? I guess tidyverse is not a good solution, I have tried to use tidyverse to solve this, but have not succeeded yet.

Comment: @Jie The last `[]` is just for printing. You'd better to read `data.table` if you want to understand its syntax. i added `dplyr` option, hope it helps you in a more readable manner.

Comment: I hope it's not a lot to ask. But can you explain the code within mutate() and filter() in plain words. Thank you! I understand variable Q was created to facilitate the filtering.

Comment: @Jie `mutate()`  adds new variables and preserves existing ones. The `filter()` function is used to subset a data frame, retaining all rows that satisfy your conditions.

Comment: this is what I got by running the code step-by-step, however I don't really understand what's going on: c(NA, data$Test_date[data$test_results == "POS"] %m+% months(3)) I got NA 11048 12054 13239 11778..., cumsum(data$test_results == "POS") + 1 I got 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3..., c(NA, data$Test_date[data$test_results == "POS"] %m+% months(3))[cumsum(data$test_results == "POS") + 1] I got 11048 11048 11048..., why these can indicate the position to filter and filter(!replace(rep(FALSE, n()), test_results == "NA" & Test_date <= Q, TRUE)) is trying to keep all rows that has variable Q with a 'FALSE' ?

Comment: @Jie `cumsum(data$test_results == "POS") + 1` spreads out the positions of `POS` occurs within each group, and `c(NA, data$Test_date[data$test_results == "POS"] %m+% months(3))` assigns the 3-month lagged date to the specific positions.

Comment: But it seems (data$test_results == "POS") + 1 capture the position of the row just after 'POS'? and c(NA, data$Test_date[data$test_results == "POS"] %m+% months(3)) added 3 months to the row identified by cumsum(data$test_results == "POS") + 1, it is the right understanding? Why c(NA, data$Test_date[data$test_results == "POS"] %m+% has 'NA' as the first value?  And what is the aim of this rep(FALSE, n())?

Comment: In my full dataset, test_results has missing values, while in the sample data, I used "NA", I think that's the reason cumsum(data$test_results == "POS") + 1 always equals NA in my full dataset. Is there a function to replace cumsum() when test_results has missing values?  Many thanks for the help, I hope you can find time to answer the question I still have in the previous comments.

Comment: @Jie `cumsm(data$test_results == "POS") ` may start from `0` if the first `POS` doesn't occur as the first one in the group. In that case, we are not able to have indexing from `0`. To take care of this case, I introduced `NA` as the head in `c(NA, data$Test_date[data$test_results == "POS"] %m+% months(3))`, which has no real meaning but just for filling one position so that `cumsm(data$test_results == "POS") +1` is feasible.

Comment: @Jie Besides, you are right, you got all `NA` since you have `NA` in `test_results`, such that `test_results == "POS"` doesn't work. You can replace all `NA` with character `"NA"` first, e.g., `replace(test_results, is.na(test_results),"NA")`